$d(x,y) = \min\{|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−y_2|, 1−|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−(1−y_2)|\}$ defines a metric on $[0,1)\times[0,1]$?
For $x,y \in [0,1)\times[0,1]$, let $d(x,y)$ be the minimum of $|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−y_2|$ and $1−|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−(1−y_2)|$. Prove or disprove that $d$ is a metric.
I was unable to find a counterexample to disprove and was able to show that
i) $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$,
ii) $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$,
iii) $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ when either $(d(x,z) = |x_1−z_1|+|x_2−z_2|$ and $d(x,y) = |x_1−y_1|+|x_2−y_2|$ and $d(y,z) = |y_1−z_1|+|y_2−z_2|)$ or $(d(x,z) = 1−|x_1−z_1|+|x_2−(1−z_2)|$ and $d(x,y) = 1−|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−(1−y_2)|$ and $d(y,z) = 1−|y_1−z_1|+|y_2−(1−z_2)|)$.
How can I proceed for triangular inequality when there are mixed distances, for instance, if $d(x,z) = |x_1−z_1|+|x_2−z_2|$ and $d(x,y) = 1−|x_1−y_1|+|x_2−(1−y_2)|$ and $d(y,z) = |y_1−z_1|+|y_2−z_2|$?
